# Shell script to read files and replace lines

Tags: scripts

I need help creating a shell script to search `.yml` files in a specific folder for a line containing `money:` and then replacing that line with `money: 1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).  E.G:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*money:.*\)/money: 1000/g' somefile.yml
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I appreciate the quick answer.